# Would a viewer see Earth from the rim of Shackleton Crater?

Tags: planet

I've been researching this but so far have not found an answer.  If you were standing on the top of the rim of Shackleton Crater at the lunar south pole, would you be able to see any of Earth? I can't find anything about the height of the rim, although nearby Malapert Mountain is apparently visible from Earth so you could see Earth from Malapert.  Shackleton, though, I'm not so sure.  Any insights appreciated. KPRedmond

Comment: Nice question, @Redmond! Welcome in this site!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As @Hohmannfan mentioned, this is a pretty strait forward physics astronomy question, if you are looking for a world building view of the question could you elaborate a bit on scenario to help us get what you are looking for?  I am sure you can get an answer here but if you are looking for a strait-forward physics answer you may want to consider flagging the question for a mod to move it over to astronomy.

Comment: For more info on the site and how things work around here, check out the [help] and feel free to join us in [chat] once you hit 20 reputation.

Comment: According to [*Physical Environment Of The Lunar South Pole From Clementine Data*](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?letter=.&classic=YES&bibcode=1995LPI....26.1339S&page=&type=SCREEN_VIEW&data_type=PDF_HIGH&send=GET&filetype=.pdf) the rim is sunlit 95% of the time. So, yes. I'd make this an answer, but this is an Astronomy.SE question.

Comment: My Stellarium places Earth very low to the South, so if you have a very clear horizon, maybe you should see it. However, it doesn't seem to be always visible.

Answer (score 4):

The moon has a monthly motion called *[libration](http://earthsky.org/space/how-much-of-the-moon-can-we-see-from-earth-lunar-libration)* Of interest to you is libration in latitude. The orbit isn't exactly in the plane of the ecliptic, and the rotation axis is slightly different from each. This means that about a week after passing its ascending node, you can see up to about 6.5 degrees past the moon's South pole. Two weeks later, the south pole is invisible, but then north pole can be seen.

From the point of view of an observer on Shackelton it would mean that over the course of a month the Earth would slowly rise and then set again.